# After cleaning a bottle, what's an acceptable amount of leftover StarSan bubbles?

Tags: cleaning, bottle, foam, starsan

I've been slowly improving my bottling, thank goodness.  I make a pot of warm / hot StarSan, and fill each bottle with the mixture, then after a while, turn each bottle upside down in the StarSan pot.  Then a few minutes later, I drain.

So far, I have ended up with a dense layer of small bubbles, about 1-2" high, at the bottom of my 750mL bottles.  I know that leaving *some* StarSan behind is OK, but I wonder if I'm not doing a thorough job of draining?  And if not, how do I get a clean drain without rinsing?

I found this question and answer about [bottling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/in-depth-cleaning-glass-bottles), and this answer about [foam](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/6990/3466), but I feel like it doesn't quite answer my question.  Perhaps I'm being paranoid, and should just relax and have a homebrew?

Edit:

I wrote this question immediately after cleaning my bottles today.  Ten minutes later, the foam has settled down to about 1/2"; much less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry about the foam, as far as I remember Charlie Tally, Head Chemist at 5 Star, has said that the starsan is broken down by the yeast. Also, when you fill the bottle most of the foam comes out as a "StarSan Worm", so there's relatively little left in the bottle.

If you've not had any problems with head in your beer then your existing methods are working fine.

Comment: Thanks, mdma, I didn't know about the yeast interaction!  As for head, I pretty much never get a head on my beer, so I don't think I'm doing it <em>quite</em> right yet.  Or, my ingredients don't lend themselves to a full head.  Will save that for another question.